# What server resources should Office Web Apps 2013 have for a mid size company?

Tags: office-web-apps

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm used by a business of 1000 people (although only half are behind computers) that will need to store, view and edit office documents in libraries.

SharePoint 2013 requires a separate Office Web Apps 2013 (WAC) farm for using the WOPI frams/protocols for in browser editing and viewing.

My question is about Office Web Apps 2013 Server specs, we currently have:

- 1 Virtual Windows Server 2012 R2 OS
- 2 cores (2ghz)
- 4gb of ram
- 60gb of disk space

But I am unsure if this is enough for an active user base of around 100 to 300? I can't find any documentation on best practice with Office Web Apps 2013 configuration, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In our premises, 1.000 users, we use the same configuration with you. I would add another disk with 60 GB. Since it's virtual, don't hesitate.